# Permission denied while taking a snapshot of running process using CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, system

Today I was requested to turn my console app(eg:App.exe) into a service, just googled and found nssm then used its effective commands to turn my APP.exe to a service,My next job is to monitor the running process(APP.exe) and if its size exceeds >30MB restart it that's all.What I've learned previously from nssm is when I kill the APP.exe  nssm automatically restart it, So now I only need to code for only monitoring and killing the APP.exe when it exceeds 30MB,finally I've created an app that does monitoring There comes the problem, In the monitoring app I have been using  `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` to take a snapshot of all running processes and try to find my APP.exe by its name then get it's size by `pmc.WorkingSetSize`, Yet When I ran my monitoring app it can't find the APP.EXE though i see it exist in the task manager I even ran it as an administrator yet it remains the same can any one helpme rid of this issue.

The error I am getting while taking a snapshot is permission denied.

please see my code below:

```
int main()
{
LOG mon;
PROCESSENTRY32 pe32 = {0};
HANDLE    hSnap;
HANDLE   hprocess;
PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pmc;
int       iDone;
int       iTime = 60;
bool      bProcessFound;

while(true)    // go forever
{
    cout<<"adjfhaljkehdfhwoefjiej";
    hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS,0);
    pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    Process32First(hSnap,&pe32);     // Can throw away, never an actual app

    bProcessFound = false;   //init values
    iDone = 1;

    while(iDone)    // go until out of Processes
    {
        iDone = Process32Next(hSnap,&pe32);
        if (strcmp(pe32.szExeFile,"APP.exe") == 0)    // Did we find our process?
        {
            DWORD processID = pe32.th32ProcessID;
            hprocess= OpenProcess(  PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                                    PROCESS_VM_READ,
                                    FALSE, processID );
            if (GetProcessMemoryInfo( hprocess, &pmc, sizeof(pmc)))
                {
                    size_t procsize=pmc.WorkingSetSize;
                    cout<<procsize;
                    if(procsize>30MB)--mylogic
                    {
            hprocess=OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE,0, processID);
            TerminateProcess (hprocess, 0);
            mon.RestartLog("Server Closed due to large size");

                    }
                }


            bProcessFound = true;
            iDone = 0;
        }
    }

    if(!bProcessFound)   .
    {

         mon.RestartLog("Server Down ");

    }
    Sleep(iTime*50);    // delay x amount of seconds.
}
return 0;

}
```

Comment: This sounds like a pretty weak way to deal with memory leaks.

Comment: Hello David, thanks for the reply!!!Where memory leak comes here?would you elaborate it please

Comment: Well, why else would decide to terminate a process when "it reaches" a certain size?

Comment: The APP.exe is gonna run on a machine with less RAM so if my APP size is keep growing then there would be a possibility of other process to get stall that's why

Comment: This is not the solution to your problem, whatever your problem is

Comment: This is the only way I know for taking memory size of an process and terminate it that's what all I have found after Googling , would you have any other way to suggest david. I could try an alternate way too if any suggested

Comment: I suggest that you stop terminating processes for no good reason.

Comment: Please read [Memory Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366779.aspx). You will start to make educated decisions, once you know how memory really is handled.

Comment: You should take better care of how you use your variables and free memory when you reach your limit or free your variables as soon as it is possible if memory is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the above said monitor app as a system process. i.e, make it as a service.

Comment: That worked, Thank much rejin!!! once i made my monitor app  as an system process(which i should as per the requirement too) it could take the snap of my APP.exe and stop the service which runs it .whenever APP.exe exceeds size >30 MB

Comment: While this works most of the time, I have come across processes which STILL throw error 5 (access denied), even while running as NT Authority\System